# Find $p$ and $q$ so that the integral converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

> Find all values of $p$ and $q$ so that the below integral converges:
>   $$
> I=\int_{0}^{1} x^p \left(\log\frac{1}{x}\right)^q\;\mathrm{d}x
> $$

I tried and got the solution as:

$q\geq0$   and $p>q-1$

$-1<q<0$   and   $p>-1$

Is it correct?

*Solution:*

After Substituting $x=e^{-y}$  the integral becomes:
$$
I=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(p+1)y} y^q\;\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Care to share your solution?

Comment: If you make another subs. $ (p+1)y =u$, then you can compare with the gamma function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

1) $\ln (\frac{1}{x}) =-\ln(x) $

2) make the change of  variables $\ln x = y$.

Answer (score 0):

Under the conditions you specified, the value of the integral is (1+p)^(-1-q) Gamma[1+q]. I hope and wish this could help.